# Bluehost marking emails from my domain as spoofed - how to fix?

Tags: email, spoofing

I am basically trying to make it so the email I send from my domain through web mail is not marked as spam or spoof. This is so as I want a profile picture to appear and not be blocked by the '?' mark in Gmail.

I have already added a CNAME through Google Postmasters, and it has been 48 hours.

Comment: I worded the question wrong. I am using Bluehost for hosting.

Comment: The description of the [tag:bluehost] tag specifically says **DO NOT USE THIS TAG**. Please do not use that tag.

Comment: Maybe try to share your DNS records if case there is an issue with your configuration?